# How can I change the center of my label with RubymotionQuery?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I want to displace the center of my label in my stylesheet. I try to use this:

```
st.frame = {l:0,t:-30,w:50,h:50}
st.text = FontAwesome.icon("search")
st.font = FontAwesome.fontWithSize(st.frame.size.height/2)
st.background_color = color.green
st.size_to_fit
st.text_alignment = :center
st.center.x = st.frame.size.width/2
st.center.y = st.frame.size.height/2
```

Buuuut...It does´t work.

Anyone can help me?

Greetings!

Comment: Do you have any more precise direction than "Displace?"

Comment: The center of label is set in the left corner of the object by default.
I want to set this center in the middle: width/2 and height/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic label, positioned in the center of the frame. You can easily displace it by adjusting the *center* attribute for the label.

```
def self.controller
  @controller ||= MyController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)
end

def viewDidLoad
  super

  @height = view.frame.size.height
  @width  = view.frame.size.width

  build_label
end

def build_label
  @label = UILabel.alloc.init
  @label.text = 'Label'
  @label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter
  # the size of the label
  @label.frame  = [[0, @height / 12], [@width / 2, @height / 6]]
  # center of label
  @label.center = [@width / 2, @height / 2]
  self.view.addSubview(@label)
end
```